# error CS1525: Invalid expression term '=' in Visual Studio on building project

Tags: c#

Im trying to do a C# simple program, but im new, and i cant understand why do i have an error here. In visual studio, there is a solution, but when i use it, its still the same error. Can someone help me or explain?

```
          float food;
            float price;
            float sdacha;
            float bills;
            float coins;
            float data;
            string agr;//agreement
            int PercentConverter = 100;

            Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

            Console.WriteLine("price: 1.25 euro");
            Console.WriteLine("how much do u want to buy?");
            food = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            price = food * 1.25f; //error CS1525: Invalid expression term '=' in Visual Studio on building project
            = Console.WriteLine($"you need to pay: {price}, do you agree?(Да/Нет)");
            agr = Console.ReadLine();


            Console.Write("Сколько у вас евро: ");
            bills = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Сколько у вас копеек: ");
            coins = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());


            data = (bills * PercentConverter + coins) / PercentConverter;
            sdacha = data - price;


            if (data >= price)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"APPROVED. Сдача:  {sdacha}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FAILED. Сдача: ");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

I tried using visuals`s studio solution, but it didnt help, still the same error, Didnt find same problem in internet too.

Comment: = Console.WriteLine($"you ...i guess

Comment: didnt saw it, oops. Visual studio showed that error is on 29 stroke. thrank you!